# Problem accessing an object with an object in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a products table and images table. A product can have multiple images. Now I want to get just one product and display it in view. I am able to get the whole object but when I display it the image part displays the whole object. How can I get the inner values.
My Vue Code

```html
<div v-for="product in Products.data" :key="product.id" class="p-2">
  <div class="item p-2">{{product.id}}</div>
  <div class="item p-2">{{product.title}} Price:{{product.price}} </div>
  <div class="item p-2"><p>Loc:{{product.location}}</p></div>
  <div class="item p-2"><p>image:{{product.images[0]}}</p></div>
  <div class="item p-2">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" :href="'/products/'+product.id">View</a>
  </div>
```

Script

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Products: {
        images: []
      },
      id: '',
      name: ''
    }
  },
```

What am getting, the results:

```
10
Bedsitter Price:6000
Loc: Opposite GG Apartment
image:{ "id": 16, "title": "26f16f925b189465.jpg", "filename": "26f16f925b189465.jpg", "created_at": "2021-01-24T16:12:35.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-01-24T16:12:35.000000Z", "pivot": { "products_id": 10, "images_id": 16 } }
```

Comment: You can use `product.images[0].id`.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari Thanks but when I do it that way I get Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". How do I define the id please?

Comment: Try using `product.images[0]['id']`

Comment: You have no `Products.data` so you cannot use it in `v-for`